# user friendly name for ADFS attributes

Tags: attributes, adfs

My application is receiving attributes for SSO Provisioning that are correctly packaged in xml and are in a SAML Response and have correct values but overlong and unfriendly names.

Example:
AttributeName="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"
AttributeValue="fred.bloggs@enterprise.COM"

Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname"
AttributeValue="Fred Bloggs"

What advice can I give to the ADFS admin to help get user friendly name, please?
For example "emailaddress" instead of 
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress

Comment: Depending on protocol used he may not have much choice. The spec describes how to send claims and using a Uri for attribute name is recommended. Why is it unfriendly?

Comment: why do you say they are `overlong`? Are you having a problem with cookie or header size?  Claims are like xml schema namespaces, they are descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

In the .NET world the [ClaimType Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.claims.claimtypes(v=vs.110).aspx) is your friend, so you don't have to deal with the actual URI.